# ASP.NET Threads and Static class

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have created `Scheduler` class which is call `MailBot.Start` static method while ASP.NET application is started. I suspect that the code is not thread safe because some variables(maybe, not sure about this) in `MailBot.Start` method is mixed. Is it true?
I would like to have only one method `running` for the whole ASP.NET app.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    WebHelper.Scheduler(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), MailBot.Start);

}


public static class MailBot
{
    public static void Start()
    {

        //The actual code...

    }
}


     public delegate void SchedulerEvent();

     public static void Scheduler(TimeSpan firstTime, TimeSpan interval, SchedulerEvent callback)
            {
                var timer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = firstTime.TotalMilliseconds };
                timer.Elapsed += delegate
                                     {

                                         timer.Enabled = false;
                                         try
                                         {
                                             timer.Interval = interval.TotalMilliseconds;

                                             callback();


                                         }
                                         finally
                                         {
                                             timer.Enabled = true;
                                         }
                                     };
                timer.Start();
            }
```

Comment: Did you read this: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Thank you for reference, contain useful information!

Comment: So are you going to call `MailBot.Start` from multiple threads?